# gRaphael Line Chart: JSON Data to Populate Popup Tags Instead of x & y Coordinates?

Tags: javascript, json, tags, popup, raphael

var times = [["1:30pm", "2:30pm"],  ["3:30pm", "5:30am"], ["12:30pm", "2:30pm"], ["9:30am", "2:30pm", "4:30pm"], ["3:30pm", "5:30pm"], ["10:30am", "12:30pm"], [] ]; I have a Raphael Line Chart based on one of the examples with the popup tags on rollover. Currently, the tag is populated with data from the Y-axis. X = day of the week, Y = a "safety score", the JSON data is times of reported incidences on each day.

I can't seem to find any documentation about how to call in a third data set to populate the tag, and I can't seem to do it with my code without breaking it. Any suggestions?

Here is my code for the tags:

```
//tags
for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
    this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 90, 0).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff"}, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
                    }
                }, function () {
    this.tags && this.tags.remove();
    //end tags
});
```

And here is my data:

```js
var times = [["1:30pm", "2:30pm"],  ["3:30pm", "5:30am"], ["12:30pm", "2:30pm"], ["9:30am", "2:30pm", "4:30pm"], ["3:30pm", "5:30pm"], ["10:30am", "12:30pm"], [] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out! Here it is.

```
var times = [["1:30pm", "2:30pm"],  ["3:30pm", "5:30am"], ["12:30pm", "2:30pm"], ["9:30am", "2:30pm", "4:30pm"], ["3:30pm", "5:30pm"], ["10:30am", "12:30pm"], [] ]; 




    //tags
    for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
                            this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i]-10, times[i].join("\n"), 90, 0).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff"}, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        this.tags && this.tags.remove();
    //end tags
});
```

Comment: Actually, that did not work. It was only creating one tag and using the same tag & data for all the data points. Help!